# Как автоматизировать действия браузера в Android?

Tags: android, selenium

Сейчас пишу бота, но под рукой пк нету. Пишу в IDEA. Думал автоматизировать всё на  js, в WebView, но появилась острая проблема в потоках. Там их должно быть пока-что 100. И вспомнил про Selenium, Appium... Но как я понял, там должен быть обязательно пк. Можно ли как нибудь использовать Selen без пк, или решить проблему с многопоточностью в WebView?

Comment: У вас в заголовке и в тексте - два разных вопроса. Синхронизируйте пожалуйста.